# ImageResizer quality option sometimes increase file size

Tags: imageresizer

We are using ImageResizer to process and resize images which works great.
However we have lately found that when using the quality command the file size sometimes increases even if you set a quality below 100. We are using no other commands, so the size of the image is the same.

When using programs or online tools for setting a lower quality to decrease file size I do actually get a lower file size with the same image. But I did get the same behaviour that the file size increased with one of the online tools.

Is this a problem in the ImageResizer compression algorithm?
Is there a way to get around this?
We have quite a few images that gets a larger file size than the source.
Google PageSpeed insights complains on these images saying that the should be compressed.

Example:
Source image: 120 kb
https://feetfirst.se/globalassets/feetfirst/ff-da-boots-1020x1166.jpg

Quality=90: 209 kb
https://feetfirst.se/globalassets/feetfirst/ff-da-boots-1020x1166.jpg?quality=90

Quality=100: 415 kb
Quality=60: 122 kb

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of jpeg compression. Every compression at the same quality increases filesize.

ImageResizer could do better, and we will, with Imageflow, but recompressing a low-quality-compressed jpeg always decreases the quality/filesize ratio. You have to lose even *more* quality to make the size go down. There are (very slow) ways to make this less bad, and we're hoping to make those methods fast enough that they can be used on-the-fly.

I'm not aware of any *fast* software that doesn't exhibit this problem - and by fast, I mean something speedy enough to occur during on-the-fly processing. Hopefully, with Imageflow (probably v2), we'll be the first to make automated-quality selection fast enough (and accurate enough) for real-world use.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass the compression?
Say that we want to use the Disk Cache function but don't want ImageResizer to apply a compression.

If we don't set any quality it defaults to 90 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `&process=no` skips processing the image.